# No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, arraylist

I am new to Spring Boot and working on database connectivity. All the related classes are here only main class having run method is not posted.

It is giving me the error of no converter found for ArrayList.

Please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

//Customer.java

```
package springbootfirstapp.domain;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

private String name;
private String phone;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Customer(int id, String name, String phone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public Customer() {
    super();
}
}
```

//CustomerController.java

```
package springbootfirstapp.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import springbootfirstapp.domain.Customer;
import springbootfirstapp.repo.CustomerRepo;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
CustomerRepo rp;

@RequestMapping("/findall")
@ResponseBody
public List<Customer> findall()
{
    return rp.findAll();
}
}
```

//CustomerRepo.java

```
package springbootfirstapp.repo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import springbootfirstapp.domain.Customer;
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
}
```

//pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringBootFirstApp</groupId>
<artifactId>springbootfirstapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEndoing>UTF-  8</project.reporting.outputEndoing>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

STACKTRACE:

[image]

Comment: please add complete stacktrace

Comment: i can't reproduce the issue using your sample - it works like a charm.. did you resolve it?

Comment: @HalkoKarr-Sajtarevic No I didn't resolve it yet

Comment: I have the same problem , but adding the dependencies didn t resolve my problem. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou everyone for the help... 
Issue is resolved by adding Jackson Mapper dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: All I see is you added jackson mapping dependency. Where is JSON mapping dependency that you added to POM.xml?

Comment: but spring boot already have all this dependencies , why add them explicitly ?

Comment: @OmarB. Yeah, you are correct, but at that time this resolved my problem, but now I am using simply jpa, jdbc and mysql dependency, and everything is working fine. Moreover, may be it was a version problem, at that time i was using 1.3.5 and now 2.1.2

Comment: @DivyaniGarg, because I m having  the same problem and I trying all solutions and still have the issue

Comment: here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698664/no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type-class-java-util-arraylist?noredirect=1#comment96216023_54698664

Answer (score 3):

Generic Guidelines for such an error is to check for :

1. No Args Constructor
2. Getters & Setters
3. Jackson dependencies

Since first two aren't a problem, Please try adding the below two dependencies and let us know if its working.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, this is not working, still giving the converter error

Comment: try changing id from int to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to add jackson mapper in pom.
Can you try that once and see your converter issue is resolved.