# Issue with converting POJOs to JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developping  a REST API and i use `Spring-mvc` (no `spring-boot`)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class restController {

    ...

    @GetMapping(value = "/sectors")
    public List<SimpleDto> getSectors() {
        return dao.getSectors();
    }
```

My dto :

```
public class SimpleDto {

    public Integer value;
    public String label;

    // with getter and setter and defalut and custom constructors
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"controllers"})
public class WebConfig {}
```

and to convert `json` i added in my **pom.xml** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything works good But when I cloned this project with `Git` to wok on it from home i got this error when i make a ajax request :

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: 
No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList]
```

I fixed it by adding this

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"controllers"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

      @Bean
      public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper()  {
        return new ObjectMapper();
      }

      @Bean
      public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());
        return converter;
      }

      @Override
      public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(messageConverter());
        addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(converters);
      }
}
```

why this error occurs only in one machine ?

Comment: The above information is not sufficient

Comment: Did you miss to create getter setter of your POJO?

Comment: @Deadpool i added some details

Comment: @AnantGoswami i added them even if my fields are `public`

Comment: It's probably related to maven on your home computer.
Try to clean with: mvn clean install
Or even think about deleting c:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository and rebuilding

Comment: Looks like you need some more dependencies like this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259077/no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type-class-java-util-arraylist-spring-b)

Comment: Remove the jackson configuration from the `WebConfig` it is configured by default when jackson is detected. You only need the `@EnableWebMvc`. Also make sure you are requesting a JSON result and not XML as the latter will fail.