# Java Spring REST - No converter found...but I have getters?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to practice REST API with Spring, but I am having an issue where it's saying

> No converter found for return value of type: class org.codestrs.resources.Employee

From what I've read, this is mostly caused by there not being a getter methods for a class, Employee in this case. The weird thing is, I do have them in there.

EDIT: Just an FYI, this is a Dynamic Web Project, and I had to build my project without Spring Boot, so I manually added the spring functionality.

```
package org.codestrs.resources;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Employee {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;
    
    Employee() {}
    
    public Employee(Long id, String name, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id; 
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.id,employee.id) &&  Objects.equals(this.name, employee.name) && Objects.equals(this.role, employee.role);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ", role=" + this.role + " }";
    }
}
```

(And here's my controller for reference)

```
package org.codestrs.controller;

import org.codestrs.resources.Employee;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
      Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        
        Employee emp = new Employee(id,"Nick","Designer");
        return emp;
      }

}
```

Looking at these, I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that you have the necessary Jackson dependencies? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259077/no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type-class-java-util-arraylist-spring-b

Comment: I guess something in your build configuration (Maven or Gradle) is wrong. Did you create a new Spring Boot project from the scratch?

Comment: Please share your pom file as well

Comment: @GregorZurowski That could be the issue. I might not have added Jackson stuff to it. However, this is a Dynamic Web Project instead of Maven, so I don't know if it would work for me without starting back from scratch.

Comment: @ElmarBrauch I was tasked to do this without Spring Boot, and I didn't do this with Maven.

Comment: @ray No pom file in this project, since it's a dynamic web project.

Comment: If you manage the project with a _Dynamic Web Project_ in Eclipse, you should be able to add the necessary Jackson libraries as library dependencies to the project.

Comment: When I try adding jackson-core and jackson-databind to my project, I get "Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception".